# Database is locked when tried to insert values in table?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, sqlite

I am creating a database for my app. I am successfully able to create the table also able to insert the value in that table. After I terminate my app, again when I launch the app & tried to insert some new values in it, it gives errorString as "Database is locked". Here is my code

> if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
>   {
>   sqlStmt = [ [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into ePubTable values ( '%@') ; " ,ePubTitle] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ] ;
>
> int retVal = sqlite3_exec ( database,sqlStmt,NULL,NULL, & errString );
>   if(retVal==0)
>       printf("Data inserted");
>   }
>
> sqlite3_close(database);

I am not able to understand why databse get locked, where I am making mistake.
Please help me out this.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the proper solution on this database locked error.
Whenever we are updating or selecting any value from database, we need to finalize the statement before closing the database else it locked your database. Syntax is as follows:

sqlite3_finalize(statement);

The bellow link help me a lot
http://iphoneramble.blogspot.com/2009/07/sqlite-and-database-is-locked.html

Answer (score 0):

the database must be copy from main bundle to documents folder to write or the database are set read-only

sorry bad english, i'm italian

Comment: At first time there will be no problem with same code. But when I terminate the app & again launch it, then onward it gives error that database is locked. If I delete database from document folder again will create then it work for first time only. Please tell me is I am doing anything wrong.